# minute average csv files

Tags: python

I have a big csv file with datetime and value recorded every 10 seconds. The csv file looks like this:

```
Datetime             Data  
2008-10-01 12:00:10, 34  
2008-10-01 12:00:20, 55  
2008-10-01 12:00:30, 46  
2008-10-01 12:00:40, 33  
2008-10-01 12:00:50, 55  
2008-10-01 12:01:00, 21  
2008-10-01 12:01:10, 2  
2008-10-01 12:01:20, 34  
2008-10-01 12:01:30, 521  
2008-10-01 12:01:40, 45  
2008-10-01 12:01:50, 32  
2008-10-01 12:02:00, 34
```

I want to write a script that would calculate minute average and write it in a new csv file giving the following output:

```
Datetime             Data  
2008-10-01 12:00:00, 40.67  
2008-10-01 12:01:00, 111.33
```

Any idea how this can be done and any suggestions about modules that I should look into or any examples.

Comment: What scripting languages do you know? This can be done in a whole plethora of languages and even in excel itself. Give us some guidance on platform or preferred language and we can help you more.

Comment: @dan360 The question is tagged Python.

Comment: why a negative vote i am learning python and i wanted to do this in python and i asked about the modules i should look into for reading.

Comment: Fair enough! - now I feel I have to try and help :) - I would prob try and get the data into a database but failing that I would probably just do some string work to sum the lines per hour and output result.

Comment: Just to clarify that wasn't me that negative voted you... I meant fair enough cos I hadn't realised it was tagged as python.

Comment: I think your example is wrong -- you are counting 12:01:00 as part of minute 12:00, rather than minute 12:01.

Comment: @dan360 i am learning python so i am interested in doing this in python..

Comment: When you say it's recorded every 10 seconds, is the CSV file being updated while you're analysing it, or is it already finished? If it's static, and can fit into memory, this sounds like a job for pandas: http://pandas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @ Thomas K the data is being recorded in a remote location and i get a mail everyday with 10 sec data for the whole day.

Comment: @Navin: So 8640 rows? That should comfortably fit in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *[csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv)* to parse the file and a dictionary to cluster the results.  The *[str.rpartition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition)* method can split-off the seconds.  Use *[sum](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum)* and *[len](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len)* to compute the average:

```
data = '''\
2008-10-01 12:00:10, 34  
2008-10-01 12:00:20, 55  
2008-10-01 12:00:30, 46  
2008-10-01 12:00:40, 33  
2008-10-01 12:00:50, 55  
2008-10-01 12:01:00, 21  
2008-10-01 12:01:10, 2  
2008-10-01 12:01:20, 34  
2008-10-01 12:01:30, 521  
2008-10-01 12:01:40, 45  
2008-10-01 12:01:50, 32  
2008-10-01 12:02:00, 34
'''.splitlines()

import csv

d = {}
for timestamp, value in csv.reader(data):
    minute, colon, second = timestamp.rpartition(':')
    if minute not in d:
        d[minute] = [float(value)]
    else:
        d[minute].append(float(value))

for minute, values in sorted(d.items()):
    avg_value = sum(values) / len(values)
    print minute + ',' + str(avg_value)
```

Comment: Why not a `defaultdict` or `setdefault`? And / or why lose the order then reconstruct it, instead of using an `OrderedDict`?

Comment: Those would have been my natural choices, but this is a beginner question, so the answer requires dirt-simple Python (with plain dicts, string methods, type casts, unformatted prints, and a minimum number of steps on each line).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the easiest way is just to treat the time as a string, rather than a time, and use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from csv import reader
from itertools import groupby

lines = """Datetime             Data
2008-10-01 12:00:10, 34
2008-10-01 12:00:20, 55
2008-10-01 12:00:30, 46
2008-10-01 12:00:40, 33
2008-10-01 12:00:50, 55
2008-10-01 12:01:00, 21
2008-10-01 12:01:10, 2
2008-10-01 12:01:20, 34
2008-10-01 12:01:30, 521
2008-10-01 12:01:40, 45
2008-10-01 12:01:50, 32
2008-10-01 12:02:00, 34"""

lines = iter(lines.splitlines())

# above this is just for testing, really you'd do
# with open('filename', 'rb') as lines:
# and indent the rest

next(lines)

for minute, group in groupby(reader(lines), lambda row: row[0][:16]):
    group = list(group)
    print minute, sum(float(row[1]) for row in group) / len(group)
```